# Typescript access protected filed

Tags: typescript, protected

I have some classes.

```
class Money {
   protected amount: number
   public equals(object: Object): boolean {
       const money: Money = object as Money;
       return this.amount === **money.amount** //<- i wants write like this
   }
}
class Dollar extends Money {
   constructor(amount: number){
       super();
       this.amount = amount;
   }
}
```

and usage

```
new Dollar(5).equals(new Dollars(5));
```

but i can't access in Money class money.amount

and then a tried like this

```
class Money {
   protected amount: number;
   getAmount(): number {
       return this.amount;
   }
   public equals(object: Object): boolean {
       const money: Money = object as Money;
       return this.amount === money.getAmount(); // tried
   }
}
```

Or in Money class delete protected suffix.

This is works but i feels this not cool.

**How can i fix this problem like java?**

Answer (score 1):

Because you have used the `protected` modifier, the `amount` property is only permitted to be accessed by instances of the `Money` class internally and is not accessible on objects of the `Money` class.

Using `object as Money` treats the object as a public `Money` object, not an internal one. Instead, you should check if `object` is an instance of `Money` first.

```js
class Money {
    protected amount: number = 0;
    public equals(other: any): boolean {
        if (!(other instanceof Money)) return false; // not a Money derivative thus not equal
        return this.amount === other.amount; // "other" is now considered an instance of Money by the compiler/linter by process of elimination
    }
}
class Dollar extends Money {
    constructor(amount: number){
        super();
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```